# What are low-level APIs and high-level APIs in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When going through reactjs documentation for animation (https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html) i came across the following two statements

> The ReactTransitionGroup add-on component is a low-level API for animation.......
>   ReactCSSTransitionGroup is a high-level API based on ReactTransitionGroup.......

What are **high-level API**s and **low-level API**s in reactjs.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A **high-level API** wraps **low-level APIs** to make them easier to use. You can still access the low-level apis if you need fine grained control.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda For example, in a **Presentational and Container Components** pair a Presentational Component is a high-level API while Container Component is a low level api. Right?

Comment: Not really, the apis are actually more like "services" built into the React library. An example of a **high-level API** would be `React.Component` and an example of a **low-level API** would be the underlying methods and functions used **within** `React.Component`. We use `React.Component` to create our class components, and it uses built in `low-level apis` to add lifecycle events and things like that under the hood.

Comment: what would be some examples of low level apis in `React.Component`.?